# Android app freezes when using different google-services.json signed apk release

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, release

I have 2 different Firebase projects, one for dev and 1 for dev.
Also I have 2 different google-services.json for each build type.

When I use the debug one, everything is working alright. When I change to release, the app freezes and doesn't even start.

I've changed the google-services.json and copied the debug one data in the release, changed release app id name to addapt it to the dev one. I sign the app, then I build it and it's working, the app doesn't freezes and has access to the Dev Firebase.

What is going on? I didn't touch anything in the json files for a long time.

```
09-14 10:46:16.943 6927-6927/? I/applabs.sharif: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-14 10:46:17.024 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/ActivityThread: Application es.sharifyapplabs.sharify is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-14 10:46:17.025 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
09-14 10:46:18.226 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: Debugger has connected
09-14 10:46:18.227 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 10:46:18.427 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 10:46:18.627 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 10:46:19.028 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/chatty: uid=10665(es.sharifyapplabs.sharify) identical 2 lines
09-14 10:46:19.228 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 10:46:19.428 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 10:46:20.830 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/chatty: uid=10665(es.sharifyapplabs.sharify) identical 7 lines
09-14 10:46:21.030 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 10:46:21.230 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/System.out: debugger has settled (1395)
09-14 10:46:21.244 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/applabs.sharif: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
09-14 10:46:21.754 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
09-14 10:46:21.840 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
09-14 10:46:21.920 6927-7084/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
09-14 10:46:21.927 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-14 10:46:21.927 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-14 10:46:21.950 6927-7086/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
09-14 10:46:21.989 6927-7086/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
    [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
09-14 10:46:22.066 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.1.23
09-14 10:46:22.092 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
09-14 10:46:22.150 6927-6927/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers: getAttributionIdentifiers should not be called from the main thread
09-14 10:46:22.298 6927-7106/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
09-14 10:46:22.558 6927-7079/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify V/FA: Collection enabled
09-14 10:46:22.559 6927-7079/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify V/FA: App package, google app id: es.sharifyapplabs.sharify, 1:494515588712:android:4cee37df0265c687
09-14 10:46:22.560 6927-7079/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 13001
09-14 10:46:22.561 6927-7079/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app es.sharifyapplabs.sharify
09-14 10:46:22.561 6927-7079/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
09-14 10:46:22.715 6927-7079/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify V/FA: Connecting to remote service
09-14 10:46:22.771 6927-7079/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
09-14 10:46:32.834 6927-7101/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/Fabric: Could not call getAdvertisingIdInfo on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient
09-14 10:46:32.838 6927-7101/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/Fabric: Could not call getId on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
09-14 10:46:42.916 6927-7101/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/Fabric: Could not call getAdvertisingIdInfo on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient
09-14 10:46:42.920 6927-7101/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/Fabric: Could not call isLimitAdTrackingEnabled on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
09-14 10:46:44.431 6927-7088/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
09-14 10:46:51.915 6927-7082/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Please provide the log cat details about the crash

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: There is no crash at all, the app just freezes, doesn't start

Comment: Why do you need two different json files? Whats wrong in using same for both release and dev?

Comment: As long as you don't have different package name, it must not affect.

Comment: It was working fine with the last 4 releases, it's so weird. I need 2 different json files because I have 2 projects in Firebase

Answer (score 0):

well, it reads:

> FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

because retrieving the token with `FirebaseInstanceIdService` had been deprecated.

> In favour of overriding `onNewToken` in `FirebaseMessagingService`. Once that has been implemented, this service can be safely removed.

you need to refactor your code accordingly.

Comment: I did this already, it was working fine 1 month ago, I just tried it today and it's not working anymore. I'm just so confused

Comment: When I debug it, it does not even go into MainApplication

Comment: I used the same key that I was using before for signing it.

Comment: I've tried now using the debug builType with the json release file, and it's freezing as well, Can't debug it, not even entering the MainApplication. I pasted the logs above

Comment: @DiegoGaspar added a more reliable answer, it was a little misleading without the log, which clearly tells what the issue is.

Comment: It's working fine in dev, this doesn't have to be the problem

Comment: `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` still seems to be the problem... and you shouldn't use that service anymore, in general (just compare to the logcat of the release build). `GCM` also was deprecated - therefore this might also affect `gms.ads`, to be replaced with Firebase ads (only a suspicion, but there is indeed a transition going on). outdated dependencies could also be involved.

Comment: Are you using Facebook SDK? It seems like latest versions of FacebookSDK have a bug that cause firebase to crash. If so, you might wanna try downgrading to v4.35.0